# Apply changes button in android studio is disabled(gray color)

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I have set up my project's minSdkVersion as 19 and enabled Instant Run .
I have deployed the app in my device running on API 21 But the "Apply Changes" button is grayed out.When I hover over the button it says `"No Active 'App' launch"` although I am running the app in my device at that time .

android studio version : 2.3

gradle version gradle : 3.3

Comment: did you launch the app from android studio or did you open it from your device after installing it ?

Comment: I have launch app from android studio.

Comment: Goto: File > Invalidate caches & restart

Comment: still it is disabled

Comment: android studio is buggy. Running 3.3 and that still happens.

Answer (score 5):

Steps to enable Apply changes option

Step 1: Enable Instant run from 
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build,Execution and Deployment ->Enable Instant Run -> Apply -> Ok.

Step 2: Check your minSdkversion should be 21 greater than that and gradle version.

Step 3: Launch your application and it will enable apply changes icon/ option. :)

Comment: For me, it's "Settings" (found in the File menu), rather than "Preferences."

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
File-> Invalidate Caches and restart
```

may be it will help you..

Comment: Still it is disabled

Comment: can you share the screenshot and screenshot of your SDK?

Comment: screenshot attached in my question

Comment: This doesn't answer the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Change **Build Variant** to *Debug*.

View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variants -> [change to *debug* if *release*]

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable it by following this path :- File/Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/InstantRun and checked the Enable InstantRun check box.